# How can I specify when Sublime Text 3 should use filetype HTML(Django), versus HTML(AngularJS), versus HTML?

Tags: django, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

I recently installed the Djaneiro package in my installation of Sublime Text 3 to offer me auto completion for Django Templates.  It's really helped speed up my django development, however now overrides my basic HTML projects and AngularJS projects to HTML(Django).

[image]

I'd like Sublime to default HTML format on static HTML projects, HTML Angular on projects that are specifically Angular, and HTML(Django) for other projects.

[image]

Although not a huge problem, it becomes a nuisance when I'm expecting HTML auto completion and the angular ng tags auto complete, or Django auto complete on standard HTML files.

Is there a way to default which HTML File type required for Sublinting I require by project?